# Condition the tensor product of a vector is not singular

Tags: tensor-products

I am generating a matrix with a vector through outer product in my code, and resulting matrix is singular. Is there a condition I can use to check the vector and figure out where the singularity comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer product of two nonzero vectors always has rank $1$ (and more generally,  the rank of a product of matrices is at most the rank of any one of the matrices).  So the only way you'll get a nonsingular matrix is if the matrix is $1 \times 1$.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry, I was actually looking at the inversion of the *sum* of $ n $ matrices resulting from the outer products. Would there be any way to pinpoint the source of singularity?

Comment: I have checked the rank of the individual matrices and found some of them with rank 0. Thank you!